# FTDI D2XX Library open multi interface devices using openByUSBDevice() call

Tags: android, ftdi, d2xx

On one of my design, I'm using a [FT4232 Quad RS232](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT4232H.pdf) IC. Since the design has multiple FTDI devices, I uses the Android USB Manager API to filter down by Vendor ID and product ID. After such a filter, what I get is essentially a [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html). But in this case, we have multiple interfaces, which the createDeviceInfoList() call will enumerate into different devices. How can I open a specific interface on a UsbDevice using D2XX library?